# Find entities by property in nested list of entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, nested, spring-data-jpa

I need to select all ScheduleOrderEntities which nested list' nested list element property is a date between...

There is no error  in below solutions, but the result is always empty, while it should have multiple values when testing with:

```
scheduleOrderRepository.findByExecutionTime(Instant.now(), Instant.now().plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
```

While there are 2 executions every day this month

each ScheduleOrderEntity has a property:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentOrder", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<SchedulePlanEntity> schedulePlanEntities;
```

And each SchedulePlanEntity has:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ScheduleEntity> scheduleEntityList;
```

ScheduleEntity has a property executionTime which I need to sort by.

Is it possible to do with jpa? There is no problem of doing it with standard query, but I want to know if it is possible with this ORM.
I have tried both:

```
@Query("SELECT soe FROM ScheduleOrderEntity soe LEFT JOIN soe.schedulePlanEntities 
spe LEFT JOIN spe.scheduleEntityList sel WHERE sel.executionTime BETWEEN 
:start AND :stop")
List<ScheduleOrderEntity> findByExecutionTime(@Param("start") Instant start, @Param("stop") Instant stop);

List<ScheduleOrderEntity> findBySchedulePlanEntities_ScheduleEntityList_ExecutionTimeBetween(@Param("start") Instant start, @Param("stop") Instant stop);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is no error in solutions, but the result is always empty, while it should have multiple values when testing

Comment: aren't you missing `select` in that `@Query`?

Comment: no, it doest not change it
I try with 
    scheduleOrderRepository.findByExecutionTime(Instant.now(), Instant.now().plus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
While there are 2 executions every day this month